# Algorithm for Comparing Two Products?

Tags: database, algorithm

I want to develop a site which can compare two products based on their features.

I want to store features as attributes in database. For example, Cellphone is a product so 'Screen Type' and 'Screen Resolution' are attributes and their values could be LED/AMOLED and 800x400/340x230.

Database could be of Cellphone/Laptop/TV but database will be for one product type only.

I want to know if there are **any algorithms to find out best of two depending on their attributes?**

Any suggestion/pointers will be more appreciated.

Comment: There is a billion-dollar industry involving companies like Amazon on comparing products.  I don't think your question is as simple as you think it is.  Can you define what you mean by `best`?

Comment: For example, I have data of 100 products. Now If I compare any two of them, instead of listing features one against other it should tell me that Product 1 is best as it has come X score and Product 2 has Y (which is less than X) score. So, depending on features of two products I want to calculate a score by which i can tell which product is best.

Comment: ParagM, Have you noticed how there is not a single dominant brand in any product? That's because a lot of it depends on what people like, and people are different. Even if you do find an algorithm for this, I wouldn't suggest using it. You can't tell anyone what is _best_ because _best_ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible algorithm, but it won't be applicable to multiple users/customers unless they share your same preferences (and disposable income!).  I've done something roughly like this when looking for an apartment:

*Step 1*: For each feature, map the different options to a numerical value.  I don't know much about cell phone screens, but let's say you consider an AMOLED screen to be worth 20% more than an LED screen.  Values that are already numeric can either be mapped discretely or using an equation.

*Step 2*: Give each feature a weight.

*Step 3*: For each feature, multiply the weight by the value; add these up and you have a score for each product.  Whichever product has the highest score wins.

---

For example, say each cell phone has these parameters:

- Screen type: LED or AMOLED
- Weight in grams
- Screen dimensions in inches, L*W
- Screen resolution in pixels, X*Y
- Battery life in hours

Mapping each parameter to a value, such that something twice as valuable is twice as high:

```
Screen type: LED => 1.0, AMOLED => 1.2
Weight: w => 50/(w+3)
Screen size: (L,W) => sqrt(L^2 + W^2) / 3
Screen DPI: (L,W,X,Y) => sqrt((X*Y)/(L*W)) / 100
Battery life: T => T / 20
```

And your relative weights are:

```
Screen type: 3
Weight: 1
Screen size: 4
Screen DPI: 2
Battery life: 2
```

Compute score for cell phone #1 with an 800x400px, 3x4 inch, LED screen, weighing 40g, with 48 hours of battery life would get a score of:

```
3*1.0 + 1*50/(40+3) + 4*sqrt(3^2*4^2)/3 + 2*sqrt(800*400/(3*4))/100 + 2*48/20
= 28.23
```

Compute score for cell phone #2 with an 100x100px, 2x1.5 inch, AMOLED screen, weighing 8g, with 200 hours of battery life would get a score of:

```
3*1.2 + 1*50/(8+3) + 4*sqrt(2^2*1.5^2)/3 + 2*sqrt(100*100/(2*1.5))/100 + 2*200/20
= 33.3
```

So the second phone is "best".  Other parameters, especially cost, should probably be included in the score.

---

Accurate results will require accurate mapping to a numerical scale and accurate relative weights - *not* an easy task, even to decide for yourself.  You could allow users to set their own relative weights, perhaps...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a score for each product you need to find the product that isn't good or doesn't fit the category. A wilson-score intervall computes this 5% error rate and you can sort your product.